# Draw asynchronous information on a graph with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I am working with an old project of codeigniter 2.X MVC. We are starting to change the JQuery for VueJS and one of the things that I have to do now is to make a graphic, quite simple.
Using axios I get the data, which is not a problem. The problem is that I can not make the graph render the information, even when I pass it on.

I have a function that creates the graph, with the information already obtained previously:

```
createChart() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('grafico-historico');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: this.labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Monto',
                        data: this.data,
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                }
            });
        }
```

I keep the information or a response object in the data () section of the component:

```
data() {
        return {
            labels: [],
            data: []
        }
    },
```

The result is an empty graph. On the other hand, if I hardcode the information of labels and data in the graph manually, if it works and shows the results.
I'm new to VueJS, so I think maybe it's a concept error or something is happening to me, could you tell me where I should pay attention? I tried to use the vue-charts library but I got exactly the same result.
I add all the code of my component so that you can get a more "global" look.

```
Vue.component('line-chart', {
    data() {
        return {
            labels: [],
            data: []
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getData();
    },
    mounted() {
        this.createChart();
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
            var labels = [];
            var data = [];

            axios.get(`/propietarios/api_buscarExpensasUnidad/${this.unidadid}`, {
                credentials: 'same-origin'
            }).then(r => {
                r.data.datos.map(x => {
                    this.titulos.push(x[0]);
                    this.data.push(parseInt(x[1]));
                });
            }).catch(e => {
                console.error(e);
            });
        },
        createChart() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('grafico-historico');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: this.labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Monto',
                        data: this.data,
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As a final clarification, I do not use .vue files since it is impossible because of the architecture of the project that we are currently using, therefore I have the component in a separate * .js file that I import in the html + php to be able to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VueJS uses Virtual DOM (like ReactJS) and

> Vue is a jealous library in the sense that you must let it completely
>   own the patch of DOM that you give it (defined by what you pass to
>   el).

src: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Therefore, library that modify the DOM directly doesn't work well with VueJS. For e.g. chartjs, jquery, etc...

`labels: this.labels,`,`data: this.data,` won't receive the updated data after your asynchronous function completes. In short, it's not a Vue component and does not work with Vue's reactivity system.

Luckily, people already made a Vue compatible ChartJs integration library(https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs) and it can work with VueJS reacivity system.

example: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/YezPLg?editors=0010

You will need to use this mixin `VueChartJs.mixins.reactiveProp` from the library to make the chart reactive.

HTML

```
<div class="app">
    {{ message }}
  <line-chart :chart-data="chartData" :options="options"></line-chart>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component("line-chart", {
  extends: VueChartJs.Line,
  props: ["chartData", "options"],
  mixins: [VueChartJs.mixins.reactiveProp],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: ".app",
  data: {
    message: "Hello World",
    chartData: null,
    options: { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.sampleAsync();
  },
  methods: {
    sampleAsync() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.chartData = {
          labels: [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July"
          ],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Data One",
              backgroundColor: "#f87979",
              data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
            }
          ]
        };
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
});
```